# Invoking new activity class when a tab is clicked in actionbarsherlock

Tags: android

Folks,

I am new to android development so my question is probably very basic - I am using the tabbed pane from actionbarsherlock and want to have 3 different UI for 3 tabs. However I also need one textbox in common across all tabs. To achieve the first thing my idea was to have 3 different activity classes extending the ActionBar.TabListener but instantiating those classes (using new) from the setTabListener is not working. Any solution?

Regards,

The Main Activity Class -

```
       ActionBar.Tab aTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    aTab.setText("A");
    aTab.setTabListener(new AActivity());
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(aTab);

    ActionBar.Tab bTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    bTab.setText("B");
    bTab.setTabListener(new MessageActivity());
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(bTab);

    ActionBar.Tab cTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    cTab .setText("C");
    cTab .setTabListener(new DataActivity());
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(cTab );
```

Now the AActivity Class -

```
  public class AActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_call);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.call, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    System.out.println("In A");
    TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aLog);

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
 }
```

It is giving me NullPointer at

```
 TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aLog)
```

so am assuming the new thing is not working at all

Comment: Please, post here your layout R.layout.activity_call

Comment: And one more thing. Maybe the super class doing something that replaces or blocking that content view which you where added on setContentView function. Try to get a sourcecode of your tabhost and see what it's doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

The `TabListener` interface allows you to respond when a tab is selected or unselected. *How* you respond to it is completely up to you. It doesn't matter if the implementing class is an `Activity` or any other particular class - as long as it implements the methods of `TabListener` in some way or another.

You should *never* have to instantiate an `Activity` class yourself through `new MyActivity()`. Android needs to do that itself so it can set up the environment for the activity. Thus, if you want to launch another activity when a tab is selected, then you should be calling `startActivity` inside `onTabSelected`. However, launching an activity when selecting a tab is probably a bad idea. That will open up a completely separate activity (outside of your original tabbed activity) and it won't have the tabbed action bar.

You're looking for **fragments**: a single activity with a container holding a fragment which you can swap with other fragments. When selecting a tab, you want to replace the current fragment with another fragment specific to that tab. This is demonstrated in the ActionBarSherlock samples, `FragmentTabs.TabManager` handles the binding between tabs and fragments. To use this in your code, you should:

1. Make your `MainActivity` extend `SherlockFragmentActivity`.
2. Grab the layout from [`fragment_tabs.xml`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/res/layout/fragment_tabs.xml).
3. Grab the `TabManager` class from [`FragmentTabs.java`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java) and copy it to your codebase (as a separate class or as a static inner class, whatever works).
4. Copy the setup code from `FragmentTabs.onCreate`:

   ```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
   mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
   mTabHost.setup();

   mTabManager = new TabManager(this, mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);
   ```
5. Create your tabs with `TabManager.addTab`, for example:

   ```
   mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tabA").setIndicator("A"),
           AFragment.class, null);
   ```
6. Make `Fragment` classes for each tab (e.g. `AFragment`). Override `Fragment.onCreateView`, inflate your UI and do some fancy stuff.

Also, read the [fragments developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)!

Comment: Matt, you're awesome.

Comment: Just trying to help! ;-) Android gives you great building blocks but from my (fairly limited) experience, you need to write a lot of code to get even the simplest use-case working. Here, you'd hope there's some built-in support for binding tabs to fragments (a very common usage), but there isn't. Luckily, the samples often fill in these gaps.